# Flutter CustomPainter: Keep path although repaint should't be done

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas, custom-painter

I have a `CustomPainter` like the one in the example. Where I don't always need to repaint, but I need to keep the previously drawn path because it is used in `hitTest`. It is also not a solution to create the `path` in the constructor because the Size obtained in the `paint` method is used to create the `path`.

In this example, `progress` can go from 0.0 to 1.0, but many times it stays at 1.0, in this case, it does not need to be repaint but the hitTest needs the path to know if the tap event is inside the `path`, in this case where `progress` is always 1.0, the `shouldRepaint` is `false` then `path` would be null as long as `progress` does not change, which generates that the hitTest is not detected correctly. I don't think always repaint is a good idea since the path would never change when `progress` is 1.0 always, but if it`s the only option I won't object.

```
class CoolPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double progress;

  CoolPainter({required this.progress});

  static Path _drawRectHole(Size size) {
    return Path()
      //Cool Drawing stuff.
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    path = _drawRectHole(size)

    canvas.drawPath(
      path!,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    return path!.contains(position);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CoolPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.progress != progress;
  }
}
```

-- edit --

The main problem is that when shouldRepait is false then path is null, which makes errors in hitTest. `progress` is obtained is obtained from 2 different Animation objects, depending on the case handled outside of the painter

Comment: i am not 100% sure about problem but have you tried to pass `Animation<double>` (instead of just `double`) and use it in `CoolPainter(this.animation) : super(repaint: animation);` constructor?

Comment: This is useful because it is practically putting `shouldRepaint() => true;` that is, it will always repaint.

Comment: it is useful because you dont have to rebuild your `CustomPainter`